# vaadin button margin top and left

Tags: vaadin

I cannot add style to my button.

In my `scss` file there is mixin with

```
.button-margin {
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 35%;
}

.v-button-caption {
    font-size: 15pt;
}
```

And while `v-button-caption` is working - when I apply style to the button via `myButton.addStyleName("button-margin");` - it does not change the location of the button.

What's the problem?

My whole button code

```
public VerticalLayout redirectButton() {
        VerticalLayout buttonLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        buttonLayout.setMargin(true);
        Button b = new Button("Redirect to another application");
        b.setHeight("50px");
        b.setWidth("400px");
        b.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                NotificationsAdminUi.getCurrent().getPage().getJavaScript()
                    .execute("window.location.href='"
                         + "http://xxxx:8080/xxxx'");
            }

        });
        buttonLayout.addComponent(b);
        return buttonLayout;
    }
```

Comment: You probably mean `px` instead of `%`? Stupid question but have you recompiled the theme? Besides, you should take caution using css margins in Vaadin layouts, it can interfere with `setSizeFull()` and the like.

Comment: It does not really matter - whether it's `%` or `px`. It does not work for me in both cases. And what to do you mean `it can interfere`? I simply want to move my button slightly down and left.

Comment: Vaadin computes width/height for you. If you change margin this way, he may not be able to compute whole size of the layout correctly, and you get unwanted overflows. Better is to use `setMargin(true)` to get a consistent margin around components. You're right about `%`, it's just not typical.

Comment: Your code definitely looks OK to me. Do you have a lot of other styles e.g. in parent components? I'd recommend looking at the resulting DOM tree using some client side debugger like Firefox's Firebug add-on, or Chrome and IE's "developer tools"  (F12).